# Remote EJB issue with Liberty and Spring Boot 1.4.2

Tags: spring-boot, ejb-3.1, websphere-liberty

I am getting the following error when making remote EJB call with Liberty Profile in a Spring Boot application.

```
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: bad address: iiop port is invalid:  vmcid: OMG minor code: 0x8
```

My code looks like this:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Object obj = ctx.lookup("corbaloc:iiop:my.host.com:9810#ejb/com/dwl/base/requestHandler/beans/DWLServiceController");
dwlServiceControllerHome = (DWLServiceControllerHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, DWLServiceControllerHome.class);
```

Error Trace:

```
[err] org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: bad address: iiop port is invalid:  vmcid: OMG minor code: 0x8  completed: No
[err]   at org.apache.yoko.orb.OCI.IIOP.CorbalocProtocol_impl.parse_address(CorbalocProtocol_impl.java:121)
[err]   at [internal classes]
[err]   at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
```

I am using JEE 7 full profile Liberty profile 16.0.0.3.

Comment: have you configured your default iiop endpoint to port 9810?  By default it's port 2809.

Comment: @aguibert I have configured like below 
<iiopEndpoint id="defaultIiopEndpoint" iiopPort="9810">
     <iiopsOptions iiopsPort="9402" sslRef="defaultSSLConfig"/>
</iiopEndpoint>

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding "NameServiceServerRoot" after port:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Object obj = ctx.lookup("corbaloc:iiop:my.host.com:9810/NameServiceServerRoot#ejb/com/dwl/base/requestHandler/beans/DWLServiceController");

dwlServiceControllerHome = (DWLServiceControllerHome) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, DWLServiceControllerHome.class);
```

We solved CORBA.BAD_PARAM error adding it to the url. Our case was invoking a deployed ejb in a WAS full from a Liberty profile